# Can I display the SerializerMethodField in Django admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-serializer

I am creating a custom field in my serializers file

```
new_field= serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

def get_new_field(self,obj):
    # do something
```

Is there a way I can display this field in the django admin panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise your django admin panel like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'new_field')
    list_editable = ('field1')


    def new_field(self, obj):
        return obj.new_field.name

admin.site.register(MyModel,MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: is there any way by which I can edit the field data from admin panel? I know I have specified read_only = True but after changing that can I edit it? And also what does .name specifies?

Comment: .name was just for example ..in this particular example there is a foreign key field called new_field in the current obj and that table has a field name .. it is accessed

Comment: to make editable fields,you can use     list_editable = ('new_field')